# Remove the first and last paragraph of url in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

**I have the code**

```
document.links [i] .href = ('http://example.com/ref=' + document.links [i] .href);
```

**When the echo show is:**

```
http://example.com/ref=https://photo.domain.com/photo1234&ab=U&bill=0ahUKEw
```

**How can I remove:**

```
https://photo. 
(and) 
&ab=U&bill=0ahUKEw
```

**Result:**

```
http://example.com/ref=domain.com/photo1234
```

I'm not good at code so I need everyone's support.

*Special thanks !*

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

First find the index of the first occurence of a dot (`.`), because that is after which you need to use(meaning, after `https://photo.`). Hence use the `indexOf` which returns the index of the character. Next find the index of the character `&`, because that is till where you need to consider the string of url.

Now that you have found both, use substring function to extract the string between the the 2 indexes. Substring takes 2 arguments, *(i)* Starting index, i.e, including the character at this index, hence use `index of`.`+1`. *(ii)* Ending index, till here string is considered without including this index.

```
var i1 = document.links [i] .href.indexOf('.');  //calculate index of "."
var i2 = document.links [i] .href.indexOf('&');  //calculate index of "&"
document.links [i] .href = document.links [i]. href.substring((i1+1),i2); //extract the string
//now do what you need to...
document.links [i] .href = ('http://example.com/ref=' + document.links [i] .href);
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. But suddenly the keywords and links of the website. How does it work only with document.links [i] .href Thank !

Comment: I'm sorry @LenaDunham. i didn't quite get you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support! <3

Comment: In this case can add ID to it only affect the area you want it? and how to do? my ifarme has id = "link1"

Comment: Sure @LenaDunham. All it just takes is to identify something distinct in what you want to remove. find the index of it and use it to get a substring. I can't tell a lot about the iFrame you have used Lena, because I can't see the full code. I surely just assist you by making this suggestion that observe the patterns and use it to apply to whatever element you are interested in. Hope this is of some help.

Comment: Do accept and upvote the answer if it has helped @LenaDunham. It will assist others in finding answers in faster to similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is it that you actually want but given the information you can try this code.

```js
var x = "http://example.com/ref=https://photo.domain.com/photo1234&ab=U&bill=0ahUKEw";

var res =  x.replace("https://photo.","").split("&")[0];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.links [i] .href = ('http://example.com/ref=' + document.links [i] .href.match(/\w*.\w*.\w\/\w*/g)[0]);
```